# Getting crash reported in crashlytics about partial apply for closure

Tags: ios, swift, closures, crashlytics

I am getting a crash reported in firebase related with - partial apply for closure. I tried answers on SO but they mainly says about use of [Weak self], I used it but still getting crash report of same. However not facing crash on my device.
Snapshot of crash report is this:
[image]

Related code of Network Manager is this:

```
//MARK: POST Methods for API Calls
func postRequest(urlString: String,
                 params:[String : Any],
                 view:UIView,
                 token:String,
                 success:@escaping (SuccessHandler),
                 failure:@escaping (ErrorHandler)) {
    
    showProgressView(in: view)
    
    let url = self.baseURL.appendingPathComponent(urlString)
    
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    if token != "" {
        urlRequest.addValue("\(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "token")
    }
    urlRequest.networkServiceType = .default
    urlRequest.cachePolicy = .reloadRevalidatingCacheData
    urlRequest.timeoutInterval = 100
    urlRequest.httpShouldHandleCookies = true
    urlRequest.httpShouldUsePipelining = false
    urlRequest.allowsCellularAccess = true
    
    do {
        urlRequest.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: [])
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    
    let task = defaultSession.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: { [weak self] (data, response, error) -> () in
        
        self?.hideProgressView()
        guard error == nil else {
            failure(error!)
            return
        }
        let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode
        if urlString.contains("signin") {
            let token = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.value(forHTTPHeaderField: "token")
            UserDefaults.standard.setValue(token, forKey: "authToken")
        }
        
        switch statusCode {
        case 200:
            if let aData = data {
                do {
                    let responseJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: aData, options: [])
                    success(responseJSON)  // Line no 160 mentioned in crash report
                }
                catch let error as NSError {
                    failure(error)
                }
            }
        case 404:
            if let aData = data {
                do {
                    let responseJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: aData, options: [])
                    let dictObj = responseJSON as? [String: Any] ?? [String: Any]()
                    let message = dictObj["message"] ?? ""
                    let error = NSError(domain: "", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : message])
                    failure(error)
                }
                catch let error as NSError {
                    failure(error)
                }
            }
        default:
            self?.logger.error("New Http Response Code")
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

Login Class method from where this api call is invocated:

```
func loginAPICall() {
    
    email = txtFieldUsername.text ?? ""
    let password = txtFieldPassword.text ?? ""
    let params = ["username" : email,"password":password]
    NetworkManager.shared().postRequest(urlString: API.signIn, params: params, view: self.view, token: "") { (response) in
        
        let arrObj = response as? [AnyObject] ?? [AnyObject]()
        let dictObj = arrObj[0] as? [String: Any] ?? [String: Any]()
        self.saveUserdata(dict: dictObj)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: ViewControllerIdentifier.ProfileLandingId) as! ProfileLandingVC
            vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    } failure: { (error) in
        print("error")
    }
}
```

Earlier i was not using [weak self], recently added after following some answers. Can someone suggest a solution for it?